# What is the behaviour of & operator

Tags: shell, background-process

I am trying to chain the commands in linux, I am using ubuntu 14.04 distribution. The aim to create a directory and go into that directory. Generally we do this

```
mkdir foldername
cd foldername
```

Perfect, when tried this

```
mkdir gates
cd gates
```

works as expected. But things are not working as expected when using **&**

`mkdir gates & cd gates`, does not work, the error is `no such file or directory`. When pressed enter, it would create the directory gates in the next step. Why this is happening?. But `ls & mkdir gates` seems to be working fine

Comment: you can just use a `;` instead of `&`. Tested in `zsh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is the [shell's backgrounding operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514); it places the command preceding it in the background and continues.

So

```
mkdir gates &
cd gates
```

starts `mkdir gates` in the background and immediately runs `cd gates`, which attempts to change the directory before it's created (and fails).

```
ls & mkdir gates
```

works because `mkdir gates` doesn't depend on anything `ls` does; all that happens is that `ls` is started in the background, outputting the directory listing, while `mkdir` creates the `gates` directory.

You're probably looking for

```
mkdir gates && cd gates
```

which will change directory only if `mkdir` succeeds; you may prefer

```
mkdir -p gates && cd gates
```

which won't fail if the directory already exists.